# Running examples in parallel in JBehave BDD

Tags: jbehave

I have a story file with 50+ examples listed below in the table and it takes really a lot of time; is there a way to run these examples in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the method useThreads(int) from the EmbedderControl class. I'm not sure it can work on just on story but you can try.

Like here :

@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public class AllStoriesTest extends JUnitStories {

```
private final CrossReference xref = new CrossReference();

public AllStoriesTest() {
    super();
    configuredEmbedder()
            .embedderControls()
            .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
            .doIgnoreFailureInStories(false)
            .doIgnoreFailureInView(true)
            .doVerboseFailures(true)
            .useThreads(1)
            .useStoryTimeoutInSecs(60);
}

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    // 
}


@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    //
}

@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    //
}
```

}